# Angular 5/6: Component Interface - is it possible?

Tags: angular, typescript

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish: create a component to wrap around MatStepper that will accept 2..n steps, each their own components.

With that said, the way that I would know how to do that in other languages would be to create an interface with the common behavior, and implement it in the different components but within the wrapper component use the interface.

**wizard-step.component.ts**

```
export interface WizardStep {
  isValid: boolean;

  nextClicked(e);
  previousClicked(e);
}
```

**wizard.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ProgressBarType } from '../progress-bar/ProgressBarType';
import { MatStepper } from '@angular/material';
import { WizardStep } from './wizard-step.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-wizard',
  templateUrl: './wizard.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './wizard.component.css' ]
})
export class WizardComponent implements OnInit {

  progress: number;
  progressBarType = ProgressBarType.Progress;

  @Input() steps: WizardStep[] = [];

  /**
   * The material stepper instance.
   */
  @ViewChild('stepper') private stepper: MatStepper;

  constructor() {
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.calculateProgress(0);
  }

  public calculateProgress(index: number): void {
    this.progress = ((index + 1) / this.steps.length) * 100;
  }

  public next(e): void {
    this.steps[e.selectedIndex].nextClicked(e);
  }

  public previous(e): void {
    this.steps[e.selectedIndex].previousClicked(e);
  }

  public selectionChange(e):void {
    this.calculateProgress(e.selectedIndex);
  }
}
```

**wizard.component.html**

```
<panel>
  <progress-bar class="progress-margins" [progress]="progress" [type]="progressBarType"></progress-bar>
  <mat-horizontal-stepper class="hide-header" #stepper (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)">
    <mat-step *ngFor="let step of steps">
      <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="step"></ng-container>
    </mat-step>
  </mat-horizontal-stepper>

  <form-buttons
    primaryLabel="Next"
    (primaryButtonClicked)="stepper.next(); next($event)"
    secondaryLabel="Previous"
    (secondaryButtonClicked)="stepper.previous(); previous($event)">
  </form-buttons>
</panel>
```

I'm then trying to use this component by creating a validation component with a component for each wizard step:

**wizard-validation.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WizardStep } from 'framework';
import { WizardValidationStep1Component } from '../wizard-validation-step1/wizard-validation-step1.component';
import { WizardValidationStep2Component } from '../wizard-validation-step2/wizard-validation-step2.component';
import { WizardValidationStep3Component } from '../wizard-validation-step3/wizard-validation-step3.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-wizard-validation',
  templateUrl: './wizard-validation.component.html',
  styleUrls: []
})
export class WizardValidationComponent implements OnInit {

  steps: WizardStep[] = [];

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.steps.push(WizardValidationStep1Component);
    this.steps.push(WizardValidationStep2Component);
    this.steps.push(WizardValidationStep3Component);
  }

}
```

**wizard-validation.component.html**

```
<wizard [steps]="steps">
</wizard>
```

And finally, **WizardValidationStep1Component**, **WizardValidationStep2Component**, and **WizardValidationStep3Component** are identical at this point:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { WizardStep } from 'framework';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-wizard-validation-step1',
  templateUrl: './wizard-validation-step1.component.html',
  styleUrls: []
})
export class WizardValidationStep1Component implements WizardStep {

  isValid: boolean;
  stepName = 'Step 1';

  constructor() {
    this.isValid = true;
  }

  nextClicked(e) {
    alert('Clicked next on ' + this.stepName);
  }

  previousClicked(e) {
    alert('Clicked previous on ' + this.stepName);
  }
}
```

With **wizard-validation-step1.component.html**:

```
<p>
  wizard-validation-step1 works!
</p>
```

---

In **wizard.component.ts**, if I use an untyped array instead of a WizardStep array, it works beautifully but of course my step components don't register the clicks, etc.

```
@Input() steps = [];
```

When used as shown above, when I try to run `ng build`, I get the following messages:

```
ERROR in src/app/wizard-validation/wizard-validation.component.ts(20,21): error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof WizardValidationStep1Component' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WizardStep'.
  Property 'isValid' is missing in type 'typeof WizardValidationStep1Component'.
src/app/wizard-validation/wizard-validation.component.ts(21,21): error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof WizardValidationStep2Component' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WizardStep'.
  Property 'isValid' is missing in type 'typeof WizardValidationStep2Component'.
src/app/wizard-validation/wizard-validation.component.ts(22,21): error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof WizardValidationStep3Component' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WizardStep'.
  Property 'isValid' is missing in type 'typeof WizardValidationStep3Component'.
```

Is the pattern I am trying to use valid in Angular 5/6? If not, is there another way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: In the lines `this.steps.push(WizardValidationStep1Component);`, you should push component instances in the array instead of component class definitions.

Comment: @ConnorsFan, same errors if I pass an instance.

Comment: Is it this error: `Property 'isValid' is missing in type 'typeof WizardValidationStep1Component'`?

Comment: Sorry - let me fix that. It actually success the `ng build` step. However, when launching the app in a browser, here's the error message: ```VueWizardComponent.html:6 ERROR Error: No component factory found for [object Object]. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    at noComponentFactoryError (core.js:3433)
    at CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (core.js:3469)```

Comment: FYI it is added to entryComponents in the NgModule.

Comment: Can you create little StackBlitz example?

Comment: in my experience ngComponentOutlet sucks hard when trying to bind inputs and outputs. What's your use case? Do you know in advance the number of steps or do you need to load them dinamically?

Comment: Would you like to do something like that : https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/steps

Comment: I know this is 3 years old, but in Angular 11 this works fine, with very simlar code to what you posted above. And you don't need to pass component instances, just classes, like in your example. The only difference is that my step interface contains a `componentClass: Type<any>` field, which is what I use in the `*ngComponentOutlet` directive. And of course you can't pass this as an input, you need to set it to each component class in code, like you do in your `this.steps.push(...)` code.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a library? [This one is cool](https://github.com/madoar/angular-archwizard)

If a library is not an option though, I would create a custom step directive and switch the step provision to the html templates.

So, instead of

```ts
// wizard.component.ts

ngOnInit() {
  this.steps.push(WizardValidationStep1Component);
  this.steps.push(WizardValidationStep2Component);
  this.steps.push(WizardValidationStep3Component);
}
```

You would do it like this

```html
<!-- something-using-wizard.component.html -->

<my-wizard>
  <my-step1-component myStep [someInput]="true"></my-step1-component>
  <my-step2-component myStep [someOtherInput]="'foo'"></my-step2-component>
</my-wizard>
```

And grab hold of your step instances in the `WizardComponent` using the `@ContentChildren()` decorator

```ts
// wizard.component.ts

@ContentChildren(MyStepDirective)
public steps: QueryList<MyStepInterface>;
```

You can inspire yourself further in the source code of the library I linked. The author does something similar...

I hope this helps you a little :-)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments `steps: WizardStep[] = [];` expects instances of the components. You pass the constructor function. The syntax for that is

```
steps: { new(): WizardStep }[] = [];
```